# Undefined Variable - PHP Code Snippet In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ebay-api

I know this has been answered many times, but I don't know why I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: urlfilter in
>   /home/mjburkel/public_html/allxxcars/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes/shortcode-php.php(52)
>   : eval()'d code on line 75

I know that this would normally be if the variable is not defined yet, but I am declaring it, thus I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.  here is my code..note this is php code that I'm inserting into a Wordpress PHP snippet plugin...so, not sure if that plugin is inserting some weird code or not reading it properly maybe?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Completed W517 */ 

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging

// API request variables
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$version = '1.0.0';  // API version supported by your application
$appid = 'XXX';  // Replace with your own AppID
$globalid = 'EBAY-US';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
$query = 'ford mustang';  // You may want to supply your own query
$safequery = urlencode($query);  // Make the query URL-friendly

$i = '0';  // Initialize the item filter index to 0

// Create a PHP array of the item filters you want to use in your request
$filterarray =
  array(
    array(
    'name' => 'MaxPrice',
    'value' => '1000000',
    'paramName' => 'Currency',
    'paramValue' => 'USD'),
    array(
        'name' => 'MinPrice',
        'value' => '100',
        'paramName' => 'Currency',
        'paramValue' => 'USD'),
    array(
        'name' => 'SoldItemsOnly',
        'value' => 'true'),
  );

  function CurrencyFormat($number)
  {
     $decimalplaces = 2;
     $decimalcharacter = '.';
     $thousandseparater = ',';
     return number_format($number,$decimalplaces,$decimalcharacter,$thousandseparater);
  }

// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function buildURLArray ($filterarray) {
    global $urlfilter="";
    global $i="";
    // Iterate through each filter in the array
    foreach($filterarray as $itemfilter) {
      // Iterate through each key in the filter
      foreach ($itemfilter as $key =>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
          foreach($value as $j => $content) { // Index the key for each value
            $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key($j)=$content";
          }
        }
        else {
          if($value != "") {
            $urlfilter .= "&itemFilter($i).$key=$value";
          }
        }
      }
      $i++;
    }
    return "$urlfilter";
  } // End of buildURLArray function

  // Build the indexed item filter URL snippet
  buildURLArray($filterarray);

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call
$apicall = "$endpoint?";
$apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems";
$apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
$apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
$apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
$apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
$apicall .= "&categoryId=213";
$apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20";

$apicall .= "$urlfilter";

// Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

// Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';
  // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    if ($item->pictureURLLarge) {
      $pic = $item->pictureURLLarge;
    } else {
      $pic = $item->galleryURL;
    }
    $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
    $title = $item->title;
    $price = $item->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice;
    $bids =  $item->sellingStatus->bidCount;
    $end = $item->listingInfo->endTime;
    $fixed = date('M-d-Y', strtotime($end));

    if(empty($bids)){
      $bids = 0;
  }

    // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
    $results .= "<div class=\"item\"><div class=\"ui small image\"><a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"200px\" width=\"130px\" src=\"$pic\"></a></div><div class=\"content\"><div class=\"header\"><a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\">$title</a></div><div class=\"meta\" style=\"margin-top:.1em\"><span class=\"price\"></span><div class=\"extra\">Sold Date: $fixed</div><div class=\"extra\"><button class=\"ui button\"><a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\"><b>Number of Bids:</b> $bids </a></button></div><div class=\"extra\"><a href=\"$link\" target=\"_blank\"><button class=\"ui orange button\">Sold Price: $$price</button></a></div><div class=\"description\"></div></div></div></div>";
  }
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
  $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using? You should actually be getting a syntax error when you first declare `$urlfilter` in your `buildURLArray()` function:

> php: error - unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in Standard input code

Because you're not supposed to be defining a variable after invoking it with the `global` keyword.

Basically, you should replace the beginning of your function with this:

```
// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function buildURLArray ($filterarray) {
    global $urlfilter, $i; // Load global variables
      //…
}
```

And `$urlfilter` should be defined in the global scope, not the function scope. You could probably just put it under `$i = '0';  // Initialize the item filter index to 0`

Comment: hey there i'm on PHP 7.1

Comment: changed my function as you advised and then declared variable as noted like this `$urlfilter='';` but now getting a different error

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: results in /home/mjburkel/public_html/allcars/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes/shortcode-php.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 1`